# Recreate object if one of the value is an array

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
{:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => [1, 2, 3]}
```

I want:

```
{:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => 1}
{:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => 2}
{:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => 3}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `hash[:value].map { |n| h = hash.dup; h[:value] = n; h }` or `Array.new(hash.size) { |i| h = hash.dup; h[:value] = h[:value][i]; h }`.

Comment: I got nerd-sniped writing a python one-liner to do this exact thing: `[(lambda i,o:(o.__setitem__("value",o["value"][i]),o))(i,o)[1] for i,o in enumerate([obj.copy() for i in obj["value"]])]`. If you need a deep copy, `import copy` and replace `obj.copy()` with `copy.deepcopy(obj)`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def doit(h)
  key, value = h.find { |k,v| v.is_a?(Array) }
  key.nil? ? nil : value.map { |x| h.merge(key => x) }
end

doit({ :foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => [1, 2, 3] })
  #=> [{:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>1},
  #    {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>2},
  #    {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>3}]

doit({ :foo => "bar", :john => "doe" })
  #=> nil
```

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks Cary!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_obj = {:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => [1, 2, 3]}

if my_obj[:value].kind_of? Array
  my_obj = my_obj[:value].map{|v| {:foo => my_obj[:foo], :john => my_obj[:john], :value => v} }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks *suspiciously* like homework, so here's some psuedocode:

```
function xyzzy (obj)
    L = length(obj.value)
    newobjs = array of length L
    for(i=0;i<L;i++)
        newobjs[i] = obj
        obj.value = obj.value[i]
    return newobjs
```

On a *totally unrelated* note, I nerd-sniped myself and wrote this:

```
lambda O,v:[(lambda o:(o.update({v:x}),o))(O.copy())[1] for i,x in enumerate(O[v])]
```

Good luck figuring out what it does.

Comment: This is for a project that I am working on, but thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: I did say "suspiciously". I usually figure it's better to send someone off in the right direction than give them the answer, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

This might go beyond what you need, but you could [make all the values into an array](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) and [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product) them together:

```
def transform(hash)
  first, *rest = hash.values.map(&method(:Array))

  first.product(*rest).map do |values|
    hash.keys.zip(values).to_h
  end
end
```

and then:

```
transform({:foo => "bar", :john => "doe", :value => [1, 2, 3]})
# => [{:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>1},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>2},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>3}]
transform({:foo => "baz", :john => "smith", :value => 4})
# => [{:foo=>"baz", :john=>"smith", :value=>4}]
transform({:foo => ["bar", "baz"], :john => ["doe", "smith"], :value => [1, 2, 3, 4]})
# => [{:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>1},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>2},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>3},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>4},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"smith", :value=>1},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"smith", :value=>2},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"smith", :value=>3},
      {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"smith", :value=>4},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"doe", :value=>1},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"doe", :value=>2},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"doe", :value=>3},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"doe", :value=>4},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"smith", :value=>1},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"smith", :value=>2},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"smith", :value=>3},
      {:foo=>"baz", :john=>"smith", :value=>4}]
transform({:foo => "bar", :john => ["doe", "smith"], :value => 4})
# => [{:foo=>"bar", :john=>"doe", :value=>4},
     {:foo=>"bar", :john=>"smith", :value=>4}]
```